# How is where clause executed in mysql in join query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables with structure as below

Table1

| Name | Quantity | PurchaseTime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| product1 | 10 | 1523825042563 |
| product2 | 12 | 1523825042565 |

Table2

| Name | Category |
| --- | --- |
| product1 | C1 |
| product2 | C2 |

I have a MYSQL Query

```
Select * 
  from Table2 
  LEFT 
  JOIN Table1 
    on Table2.Name = Table1.Name 
 where Table1.PurchaseTime > 1523825042563;
```

How will this query be executed in mysql?

Join will be done and then where clause will be executed later? If so Assume Table2 has 1 million rows, So 1 million rows will be selected, will be joined with table 1 and where clause will be executed?

Is this a good database design?

Comment: You may not be asking the right question here.  In the absence of any indices, MySQL will do a brute force scan of the table on the left against the table on the right.  If you _tune_ your query, you can optimize it.

Comment: In general, arguments for the LEFT-JOINed table should be in the ON clause

Comment: It looks like table1 are orders, and table2 are products. If you need the products info of each purchase made, I would prefer to make query table1 INNER JOIN table2.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Table is indexed on ProductName.  What is the optimization your'e referring to?

Comment: @iguypouf, Requirement is products(Data from Table) which are ordered after a specific time.. Time is only available in Table1. 

Query is working fine. But as Tim mentioned, I am also doubtful of the brute force scan, That the reason for the question

Comment: May I know what is the purpose of `LEFT JOIN`? Cause the `where Table1.PurchaseTime > 1523825042563;` is just turning it into `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: @FaNo_FN Your'e right. LEFT JOIN doesn't make any sense. It was done that way.  INNER JOIN Might be the correct usage

Comment: The answer to your question is the `explain` plan.  If this is something you care about, learn about this functionality:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/explain.html.